# Prevent Angular from updating base href with langcode

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have problem with angular v9. I have implemented i18n localization features into my app. When I try to build my application with certain location it constantly adds the sub-folder to the base href path (but I want to keep files in the sub-folder). 
Is there any way to prevent adding the locale into the base href url?

Reproduction steps:

1. Generate dummy project `ng new Project`.
2. Build production config `ng build --prod --localize`.
3. Files are built into `dist/en-us/` folder, but the `index.html` has `<base href="/en-US/">`.

**Is there any way to force angular to stop adding the langcode into base href?** 
This inflicts all the app links to contain language code, which is unwanted.

My deployment is configured to deploy the application based on the directory into different location which every will be at root.

- hxxp://app.fr/ root in `/fr/` folder
- hxxp://app.de/ root in `/de/` folder

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution in this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17260

You have to write for each locales and for your sourceLocale the baseHref

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": {
        "code": "en",
        "baseHref": ""
    },
    "locales": {
        "fr": {
            "baseHref": "",
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Posting with my solution, but that kills the new feature of Angular v.9.

The solution is to not use `--localize` flag.

So I removed definition:

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "de",
    "locales": {
      "fr": "src/app/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
}
```

Then I created custom configuration under:

```
  "configurations": {
    "fr": {
      "i18nFile": "src/app/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
      "i18nLocale": "fr",
      "outputPath": "dist/fr"
    }
```

And just called:

```
ng build --configuration=fr
```

But that is ugly.. so waiting for some better ideas :)

Comment: ..marking my own response, as there are no better answers :(

Answer (score 1):

You can override baseHref with this:

```
"locales": {
  "de": {
    "translation": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf",
    "baseHref": "/"
  },
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Dockerfile:

RUN sed -i  "s/<base.*//" /usr/share/nginx/html/nl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can stop to generate locales in your dist while build the project. For Ex.: `/dist/project_name/en_us/`.
Remove below line from angular.json file.

```
"localize": true,
"i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
```